# How do I pass the changed hidden field value from ValidateForm JS function to MVC controller

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor

I have a hidden field in my view and I'm trying to add a value to it in the validateForm() JavaScript function. I see the value is getting changed on the output window. However, Model that is being passed to controller as a parameter receiving it as Null.

Here is the code that I have tried

**Cshtml:**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ViewAch", "AchNew", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", id = "CreateACHForm", onsubmit = "validateForm()" }))
{
    <label>First Name <span>*</span></label>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FirstName, new { maxlength = 19, @class = "input-required form-control form-control-sm", id = "fname" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.FirstName, "")
    <label>First Name <span>*</span></label>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FirstName, new { maxlength = 19, @class = "input-required form-control form-control-sm", id = "fname" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.FirstName, "")
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken();
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.TokenizedPayloadNonce);
    <input type="submit" value="SignUp" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" />
 }
```

**JavaScript:**

```
function validateForm() {
    var NewToken = callExternalSytem(); // retrieving value from the external system
    document.getElementById('TokenizedPayloadNonce').value  = NewToken;
}
```

Here is how I'm reading it from the controller:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult ViewAch(AchProfile achProfile)
{
    var token = achProfile.TokenizedPayloadNonce;
}
```

I am able to access the other field values but not the ones that I updated in validateForm(). Is there something that I'm missing?

Comment: Update your view content to include more code, please. How you perform the `submit`? Did you check the console log for any errors?

Comment: Hi, I just updated the view content and I don't see any errors in my console log.

Comment: @Vanitha Instead of `@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.TokenizedPayloadNonce);` , try this: `<input type="hidden" id="TokenizedPayloadNonce" name="TokenizedPayloadNonce" value="@Model.TokenizedPayloadNonce"/>` and then try to post your form and check if you get the value as expected.

Comment: Hi @RahulSharma, I am getting "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" exception for this

Comment: @Jackdaw, It working for me ONLY when  document.getElementById('TokenizedPayloadNonce').value  = NewToken; is outside validateForm().
When it is written inside validateForm(), I'm getting null

Comment: @Vanitha Where are you getting this error?

Comment: @RahulSharma, at input field
<input type="hidden" id="TokenizedPayloadNonce" name="TokenizedPayloadNonce" value="@Model.TokenizedPayloadNonce" />

Comment: @Vanitha Try this: `<input type="hidden" id="TokenizedPayloadNonce" name="TokenizedPayloadNonce"/>`

Comment: @RahulSharma Now, the runtime error is gone but the hidden field value is coming as Null in controller

Comment: Yes @RahulSharma. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding your case, you can use this method to send the updated value to your `Controller`:

We first change the type of your `SignUp` from `submit` to `button` and bind the `validateForm` to its `onclick` event :

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ViewAch", "AchNew", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", id = "CreateACHForm"}))
{
    <label>First Name <span>*</span></label>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FirstName, new { maxlength = 19, @class = "input-required form-control form-control-sm", id = "fname" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.FirstName, "")
    <label>First Name <span>*</span></label>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FirstName, new { maxlength = 19, @class = "input-required form-control form-control-sm", id = "fname" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.FirstName, "")
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken();
    <input type="hidden" id="myTokenizedPayloadNonce" name="TokenizedPayloadNonce"/>
    <input type="button" value="SignUp" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" onclick="validateForm()" />
 }
```

Once the binding is done, then we use `Javascript` to submit your form to the `Controller`. This will bind the updated value that you required to your `Model`:

```
function validateForm() {
    var NewToken = callExternalSytem(); // retrieving value from the external system
    document.getElementById('myTokenizedPayloadNonce').value  = NewToken;
    document.getElementById('CreateACHForm').submit();
}
```